# Can the duplicate-selection pop-up be made 18px wider?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, close-dialog

<sup>... or can the question-preview within the duplicate-selection pop-over be made 18px thinner?</sup>

As it stands, the duplicate-selection pop-over has a horizontal scroll bar to cover these extra 18px, which is *just* enough to miss off the last word of a each line in some situations, and *more than enough* to drive me potty and to make me want to jump out of my window.

> [image]

([meanwhile...](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_S4rqtpLktRc/S_QDVPvtWoI/AAAAAAAAArE/72o5S4B-oj0/s1600/angry.jpg))

Is there any chance, that, for the sake of my sanity, that this need-for-scrolling can be removed somehow?

---

<sup>(Chrome, Windows 8, incase it's a browser bug).</sup>

Comment: I don't think it's too much to ask, assuming it wasn't made that way for a reason (maybe a sneaky way of deterring those who don't take it seriously and often make bad choices).

Comment: You should add the image to the post as well, for better describing the situation ;)

Comment: Confirmed in Chrome on a Mac, but [only when "always" showing the scrollbars](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dz9Ia.png). With the OS X (annoying) default, to only show scrollbars when scrolling, [all is fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kdnnU.png). This still might be a CSS issue, of course. But just to be sure: does Windows 8 show scrollbars by default?

Comment: @Arjan: Mmmm, not too familiar with the functionality you're describing on OSX, but on Windows 8, the scroll bars are visible whether I'm scrolling or not (if that's what you mean...?)

Comment: Indeed, @Matt. On OS X that's no longer the default, but as I have re-enabled my scrollbars to always be shown if scrolling is *possible*, even when I am not actually scrolling, some sites just don't align perfectly anymore. But if Windows 8 always shows scrollbars when you can scroll, then you're not to blame for some special settings you did *not* change :-)

Comment: @Arjan: How are you supposed to know what *is* scroll-able in OSX without scrollbars? :/

Comment: You're very right, @Matt, I don't understand that either, and I feel that default is *very* annoying. Luckily, for now, Apple still allows one to disable that... On the other hand: on many mobile devices you don't know there's scrollable content either.